# Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, cordova

I have attached full log for cordova build, please suggest how to fix this:

```
cordova build android
....
....    
:processDebugResourcesC:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:170: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:176: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:182:21-37: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:184: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Design.TextInputLayout'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:190:21-32: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:192:21-42: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlActivated'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:191:21-39: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlNormal'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:200: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:203:21-40: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionMenuTextColor'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:204:21-36: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:170: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:176: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:182: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:184: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Design.TextInputLayout'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlActivated'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorControlNormal'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:200: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:203: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionMenuTextColor'.

C:\Users\sushovan\IdeaProjects\cometchat-cordova-sampleapp\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:204: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

- I have done with cordova platform update android, nothing happen.
- I have done with cordova platform remove android; cordova platform add
  android;

Comment: Which Cordova and Cordova-android version you are using ?

Comment: cordova --version = 7.1.0
cordova platform = android 6.3.0

Comment: have you tried removing and adding platform again by `Cordova platform remove android` and `Cordova platform add android`

Comment: yes, tried, nothing happens. same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with cordova and android 7.0.0.
**That helped:**

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
brew reinstall node

sudo npm install -g cordova
npm i -g npm to update

cd my_project
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```